# AWS EC2 add more Public IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip

My EC2 has 1 Elastic IP but I need to add second elastic IP.

I try to create a new Network interface then add second elastic IP to it, after reboot I receive a new interface with private IP but I can't SSH to the server by new Public IP.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to assign second private IP to new network interface.

Try this and change secondary_private_ip with its new private IP.

```
sudo ip addr secondary_private_ip/20 dev eth0
```

Comment: now i have secondary private IP after added new interface but how I make new Public IP work ?

Comment: Just go to your elastic IPs section in AWS Web Dashboard and associate it with a network interface and your private IP address.

You can also use CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-address.html

Comment: ok, I added my EIP to a new network interface but still cannot ssh to new Public IP
on my instance Elastic IP show 2 IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx* (old) and xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx* (new)